# Is "Fast Factoring Integers by SVP Algorithms, corrected" correct?

Tags: rsa

Schnorr [comes again](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/933). Will he really break RSA this time? But he still didn't give any concrete examples that can enable us to quickly verify his claim.

Comment: He fixed the 'destroyes' --> 'destroys' which took away the charm from it.

Comment: [Earlier question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88582/555) on the [earlier article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/232).

Comment: I stand by my answer to the previous question (I'm not sure there is a point in re-posting that as an answer): if the claim was true, then there would be an extremely simple way to prove it: 10^10 arithmetic operations is nothing. There are tons of 800-bit factoring challenges available online. The author could just solve them and include the factorization in the submission; the lack of such a straightforward validation should be taken as empirical evidence that the claim is, as of today, unsubstantiated at best.

Comment: Kind of agree, but the fact that the author thinks that there is a more efficient way to refactor doesn't mean that it is necessarily easy to implement the attack. That said, so far all attempts have failed it seems.