# Schnorr RSA factoring (round 2)

Tags: rsa, lattice-crypto

### Introduction

Earlier this year Claus Peter Schnorr claimed to have "broken RSA". The original paper was discussed in [Does Schnorr's 2021 factoring method show that the RSA cryptosystem is not secure?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88582/60866). A [revised version](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/933) of his paper was posted on the iacr about a week ago and as per @fgrieu's comment, someone attempted to start a discussion around it: [Is “Fast Factoring Integers by SVP Algorithms, corrected” correct?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/92022/60866).

I decided to give it a go and I found myself utterly mystified by an early claim in the paper. He considers a permutation $f$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and defines column vectors $b_1,\dots,b_n,b_{n+1}$ as below

[image]

where $p_1=2,p_2=3,\dots$ are the first $n$ primes and $N'$ is irrelevant to my issue (I presume). He considers a linear combination with integer coefficients $e_1,\dots,e_n$ of the first $n$ vectors

$${\bf b}=\sum_{i=1}^n e_i{\bf b}_i \in \mathcal{L}(R'_{n,f})$$

sets

$$u=\prod_{e_i>0} p_i^{e_i}, v=\prod_{e_i<0}p_i^{-e_i}\in {\mathbb{N}}$$

and writes

$$\hat{z}_{{\bf b}}=N'\ln{(u/v)}$$
for $b$'s last (i.e. $(n+1)$-th) coordinate.

### Issue

The issue I have is with the estimate of a lower bound for $\|b\|^2$ that follows. Schnorr writes

[image]

This seems to be false on the face of it: it asserts that
$$\sum_i e_i^2f(i)^2 \geq\sum_i |e_i|\ln(p_i)$$
But if the permutation $f$ is chosen so that, say, $f(n)=1$ then choosing $e_n=1$ and all other $e_i=0$ yields
$$1\geq\ln(p_n)$$
which, unless I'm missing something, is patently false.

Furthermore, unless $e$ is the zero vector there is no way that the claimed inequality can ever be an equality since, upon removing the $\hat{z}_b^2$ term from both sides, the right hand side $\ln(uv)$ is irrational, being the natural log of an integer $uv\geq 2$, whereas the left hand side, $\sum_i e_i^2f(i)^2$, is a positive integer.

Am I missing something? Can someone guess the correct statement he is trying to prove?

Comment: [Other question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/92022/555) about the same article.

Comment: @fgrieu thanks.