# Does the article "Factoring integers with sublinear resources on a superconducting quantum processor" affect ECC?

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, quantum-cryptanalysis

["Factoring integers with sublinear resources on a superconducting quantum processor"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.12372.pdf) seems to indicate the end is getting closer for RSA - much faster than anticipated earlier:

> We proceed by estimating the quantum resources required to factor RSA-2048. We find that a quantum circuit with 372 physical qubits and a depth of thousands is necessary to challenge
> RSA-2048 even in the simplest 1D-chain system. Such a scale
> of quantum resources is most likely to be achieved on NISQ
> devices in the near future.

But does this method affect ECC?

In other words: If we get the NISQ device needed to break RSA-2048 using the method above, will that affect ECC with a comparable strength?

Can we buy some time by moving to ECC now, so [we can wait for the pqcryto to be standardized](https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2022/07/nist-announces-first-four-quantum-resistant-cryptographic-algorithms), before we move to pqcrypto?

Comment: We have a [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/103745/555) about that aspect of the linked article. In said article, the 24 authors discuss a technique purported to improve how hypothetical [Cryptographically Relevant Quantum Computer](https://crqc.grieu.fr) could factor integers, thus break RSA. It's unclear if the idea holds water. And there's neither a word about ECC, nor any advance towards CRQC hardware. The present comment is not an answer, it only aims at giving context.

Comment: Also discussed at length [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/103581/quantum-computing-used-to-break-rsa-by-fixing-schnorrs-recent-factorization-c). Short version: the article is misleading (read: wrong) and does not threaten RSA in any way.